# How to remove duplicate XML declaration

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jersey, jersey-client

I am receiving following XML response via Jersey client

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><aaa><bbb key="Data"><?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<my-data xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="MyData.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <data name="abc" uniqueId="4fe95637-a381-4e0c-bf7f-49f794df5f23">
        <variable var1="xyz" value="44"/>        
    </data>    
</my-data>
</bbb></aaa>
```

I am saving this as an XML file and getting 'premature end of file' error during parsing, since the XML is malformed (duplicate XML declarations)...is there a way to remove following duplicate entry from the output?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
```

Following is my Java code snippet:

```
 String output = response.getEntity(String.class); 
 file = writeResponseToFile(output,"MyData.xml");
 DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
 dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);       
 DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
 Document document = db.parse(file);    //Error
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally, you should fix the problem at the source.  What you're receiving is not XML because having more than one XML declaration violates XML's basic grammar, making the data not well-formed.

If it is impossible to properly fix the problem at the source, and you wish to attempt repair, you have to treat that data as text, not XML, until you remove the extra XML declaration (via text-level operations, not XML parsing).

Answer (score 0):

Fix the xml that you are receiving. You receive two declarations in the xml.

The xml is malformed. Remember in Jersey, you can receive files on JSON, xml, html, etc, via annotations, with @Produces.

And remember that you have xml validators on internet, to valid your xml.

Regards.